# Using same query for different DbSets in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two different views to the same database table and I would like to use same query against both views.

I have now following ugly solution where I have basically copy of the query.

```
DbSet<uvw_MyView1> view1 = entities.uvw_MyView1;
DbSet<uvw_MyView2> view2 = entities.uvw_MyView2;

if(doQueryOnView1)
{
    // huge query
    view1.Where(jada jada)
}
else
{
    // huge query copied here with exception of different DbSet
    view2.Where(jada jada)
}
```

What I would like to have is more elegant solution. Basically I want to have same query part for two DbSet's that are in column wise exactly same, but those return different rows. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add interface containing all properties of your view and implement this interface by both view entities. After that create method containing whole your query:

```
public static IQueryable<T> YourHugeQueryMethod<T>(DbContext context, ...) 
     where T : class, IView, new()
{
    DbSet<T> set = context.Set<T>();
    return set.Where(...);
}
```

Comment: Great! Probably easiest way to add those interface definitions is to create partial class for those views (DbSet).. I'll try this right away.

Comment: Works now smoothly. Only thing I had to do is to change the method signature: "public static IQueryable<T> YourHugeQueryMethod<T>(DbContext context, ...) where T : class, IView, new()". Error came from having interface before class restriction. Thanks!